# How to calculate the true length of day on a celestial body?

Tags: orbit, planet, rotation, mathematics

When I only know the sidereal rotation period, how do I determine the true length of day on a body?

We know the Earth's sidereal day doesn't have full 24 hrs unlike the true length of day. It's similar on Mars where the sidereal day isn't as long as a Sol (about 24 hrs 40 min) either. So how do we calculate the true length of day on a planet?

Let's do it on the example of the planetoid Ceres: its sidereal rotation period is 9 hrs 4 min and 27 sec. How do we calculate the true length of day on Ceres?

Comment: You mean the mean Solar day? You would have to know the period around the star

Comment: Note that the "true" or apparent day length (the time from one high noon to the next) generally differs from that of the mean solar day. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/469884/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring I was asking on the mean solar day however, what on Earth is 24 hrs and on Mars about 24 hrs 40 min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the length of a sideral day and the length of a year, you can determine the length of a solar day.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time#Sidereal_days_compared_to_solar_days_on_other_planets):

[image]

After one year, there will have been one more solar day than sideral day. Therefore :

solar day = sideral day / (1 - (sideral day/orbital period))

Comment: From this I conclude that the farther the object is from the Sun, the smaller the difference between the length of the sidereal and of the solar day?

Comment: @user30007 Yes, indeed.